# Set part/range of list to specific value

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list of tuples like so:

```
{{24, 29}, {155, 161}, {185, 193}, {220, 224}, {229, 234}, {251, 
  256}, {290, 297}, {394, 406}, {568, 586}, {648, 654}, {691, 
  696}, {760, 772}, {852, 856}, {860, 864}, {923, 929}, {954, 
  958}, {984, 992}, {1099, 1108}, {1138, 1144}, {1179, 1185}}
```

that corresponds to intervals on the number line from $1$ to $1199$. Given this list of tuples, I want to construct an array of zeros and ones such that the array takes on the value $1$ only between the intervals (ends points included). I have spent the better half an hour trying to figure this out without success.

My solution was along the lines of:

```
ArrSet[ints_] := 
 Module[{x = ConstantArray[0, 1199]}, (Scan[
    x[[#[[1]] ;; #[[2]]]] = 1 &, ints]; x)]
```

But I can't get it to work. What am I doing wrong?

---

For context, the list of intervals is a value in an association. Once I have a working `ArrSet`, the intention is to modify it to `ArrSet[key_, ints_]` and do a `KeyValueMap` on the association so that each key/value pair has its own one-zero array.

Comment: You can e.g. define a function pred, that gives 1 or 0 ,depending on the argument being a member of an interval or not. E.g: dat = {{24, 29}, {155, 161}, {185, 193}, {220, 224}, {229, 234}, {251,
     256}, {290, 297}, {394, 406}, {568, 586}, {648, 654}, {691, 
    696}, {760, 772}, {852, 856}, {860, 864}, {923, 929}, {954, 
    958}, {984, 992}, {1099, 1108}, {1138, 1144}, {1179, 1185}};
pred[x_] = AnyTrue[dat, (#[[1]] <= x <= #[[2]]) & ]; pred /@ Range[1199]

Comment: @DanielHuber That might be a workable solution ... going to try that approach. Do you know what is wrong/breaking in the question's code? That seemed more direct/cleaner but just won't work.

Comment: Yor codes does not work because "&" (function) has a low precedence. If you use brackets it will work: ArrSet[ints_] := 
 Module[{x = 
    ConstantArray[0, 1199]}, (Scan[(x[[#[[1]] ;; #[[2]]]] = 1) &, 
    ints]; x)]

Comment: I would have never figured that on my own ... .

Comment: Pay attention to the color of the slots (`#`). In your code, the slots are pink-ish and they should be green.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
tuples = {{24, 29}, {155, 161}, {185, 193}, {220, 224}, {229, 
   234}, {251, 256}, {290, 297}, {394, 406}, {568, 586}, {648, 
   654}, {691, 696}, {760, 772}, {852, 856}, {860, 864}, {923, 
   929}, {954, 958}, {984, 992}, {1099, 1108}, {1138, 1144}, {1179, 
   1185}}; 

sa = SparseArray[Thread[Join @@ Range @@@ tuples -> 1], {1199}]
```

[image]

```
Normal @ sa
```

[image]

You can also do:

```
m1 = ConstantArray[0, 1199];
m1[[Join @@ Range @@@ tuples]] = 1;
m1 == Normal @ sa
```

> ```
> True
> ```

```
m2 = MapAt[1 &, ConstantArray[0, 1199], List /@ (Span @@@ tuples)];
m2 == Normal @ sa
```

> ```
> True
> ```

```
m3 = ConstantArray[0, 1199];
Do[m3[[Span @@ t]] = 1, {t, tuples}]
m3 == Normal @ sa
```

> ```
> True
> ```

```
m4 = ReplacePart[ConstantArray[0, 1199], 
        Alternatives @@ Join @@ Range @@@ tuples -> 1];

m4 == Normal @ sa
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Comment: I am trying to avoid saying "Thanks" so let me say: This answer is very detailed and adds more than one way to solve things (when it didn't have to). The `MapAt` solution and `ReplacePart` solution are closer to my way of thinking and it is good to know they exist and that there is so much to learn about this language!

Answer (score 2):

**Using `Interval` functionality:**

```
subints = {{24, 29}, {155, 161}, {185, 193}, {220, 224}, {229, 
   234}, {251, 256}, {290, 297}, {394, 406}, {568, 586}, {648, 
   654}, {691, 696}, {760, 772}, {852, 856}, {860, 864}, {923, 
   929}, {954, 958}, {984, 992}, {1099, 1108}, {1138, 1144}, {1179, 
   1185}};

intunion = IntervalUnion @@ Interval /@ subints;

arr = Boole[IntervalMemberQ[intunion, Range[1199]]];
```

---

Visualization:

```
Partition[arr, UpTo[40]] // ArrayPlot
```

[image]

---

**Addendum**

Stepping into weirdness:

```
pos = Flatten[Range @@@ subints];
n = 1199;
2^(n - #) & /@ pos // Total // IntegerDigits[#, 2, n] &;
arr2 == arr
```

> (*True*)

Comment: (+1) I really liked that you added visualization. :-)

Answer (score 2):

```
p = {{2, 6}, {11, 11}, {18, 20}};

z = Array[0 &, 20];
```

---

Grabbing the @eldo's data and using `Table`:

```
Table[If[Or @@ Thread[k == Flatten[Range @@@ p]], 1, #[[k]]], {k, Length@#}] &@z

(*{0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1}*)
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple but interesting problem

```
p = {{2, 6}, {11, 11}, {18, 20}};

z = Array[0 &, 20];
```

Using `SubsetMap` (new in 12.0)

```
f[z_, p_] := SubsetMap[Array[1 &, Length @ p] &, z, p]

Fold[f, z, Range @@@ p]
```

{0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1}